# Tweak Tool appearance bug

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, unity-tweak-tool, gnome-tweak-tool

When I opened Tweak Tool in Ubuntu 14.04 Unity, it starts fine, but after switching tabs, the main panel becomes **transparent** for some peculiar reason.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Similar bug was seen when I opened tweak tool in Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome, but instead of transparent, the main panel was completely black.

How to fix this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an older bug that has been documented on the launchpad as [Bug #1304092](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweak-tool/+bug/1304092).

A suggested solution there is to run the following:

```
$ gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```